# How do I increase the text size in my android textview based on loaded text?

Tags: android, text

I have a textview that displays text I load from a database. Sometimes the text is a single letter like `b` and sometimes it's two words that go over two lines like `small word`.

If I display a single letter I want the font size to be bigger. I tried using the html font tag with the [size](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) attribute and pass the string through `Html.fromHtml()`:

```
<font size='6'>d</font>
```

However unfortunately the font size doesn't change and Android doesn't seem to recognize the attribute.

I don't want to give the font size in `px` because the I sometimes want to load the text in textviews with a different default textsize.

---

More detail:
I have an app that asks the user a series of questions.  To do so it displays two possible answers in two separate `textview`s. I have a few thousand questions in my database. The activity runs for 3 minutes at a time and I expect the user to answer a question every three seconds.

Sometimes the answer is a one-line word, sometimes it's take two lines and sometimes it's a single letter. In cases where it's a single letter I feel like I'm wasting space by displaying the letter in the same textsize, so I want to increase it's textsize.

In the field where the question is displayed, I have a similar issue. Sometimes the question takes two lines and sometimes it takes a short one-line word. When it takes one-line I also want to increase the font size.

[image]

Comment: You do realize that there is a textSize property for `TextViews`, right? Anyway you can measure the size of the text on the screen and then adjust the textSize accordingly.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : I know that I can read out the tag via regex myself and then change the the textSize but to me that doesn't look like an obvious solution and I have the feeling that there should be a more straightfoward way. As far as measuring the text size on the screen and dynamically changing the textsize can you send me to a resource?

Comment: What are you talking about? Regex? The `TextView` itself has a`setTextSize()` method. You can use it to set your text size for example according to the width the text by calling `getTextBounds()` and comparing it to the available size. You can also measure the width of the text with a `Paint` instance which might be preferable.

Comment: And I recommend that you don't use any `Spannable`s to style your texts. They never work that well. Especially `Html.fromHtml()`. There is never a reason to use that... Well aside from some very special circumstances.

Comment: I want to load the string from the database. The knowledge about the textsize is contained in that string. Regex would be a way to get it out.

Comment: You mean you save a html string like in your question in your database? Why? That's terrible. And unless the user specifically picks a textSize you shouldn't save it in any case.

Comment: Don't format your text with html.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Because I have a lot of data. The string might have a thousand different values.

Comment: I just don't get at all what you are doing. Why are you using html to format your text? Why are you saving those html strings in your database? If you have to save a text and its size then why not just use two separate columns? Why are you trying to use html to set the textSize of a text? Why do you have to save the textSize anyway? Is it something the user sets? If yes, then have you ever thought about just saving the user setting and using sp values mapped to each setting to set your textSize like normal?

Comment: You are just barely mentioning so many important details, I'd you don't explain exactly what and why you are trying to do all this then nobody can give you any meaningful advice.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is: Do you know what you are doing and everything you are telling me has a specific and very good reason why you are doing it this way or is it just that you don't know of any other or better way to achieve what you are trying to do?

Comment: @XaverKapeller : I would rate my knowledge as medium. I'm no completely noob but I'm also no expert.

Comment: If you explain to me what exactly you are trying to do I might be able to help you find a great solution.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : I added more details of my usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

I have created a CustomTextView class overriding the `ondraw` method to `setTextSize` dynamically instead of setting each TextView.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
  private static final String TAG = "CustomTextView";

  public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }

  @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getLineCount() == 1) {
      setTextSize(40);
    } else {
      setTextSize(20);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }
}
```

**layout_custom.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    >
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:weightSum="1"
      >
    <com.example.blizzard.sof.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/customtextview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="Word1 \nWord2"
        />

    <com.example.blizzard.sof.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/customtextview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="B"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure you replace the `com.example.blizzard.sof.CustomTextView` with appropriate package name.

Preview:

[image]

Previous Answer:

You can make use of [**AutoFitTextView**](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) library.

Convert all your textviews to `AutofitTextView` and make sure to set the appropriate value for the attributes `android:textSize="?"` &
`autofit:minTextSize="?"`.

**Sample:**

[image: AutoFitTextView]

Comment: It seems to me like this library reduces the text size if a line doesn't fit on the required width. On the other hand it seems to me that if the height of the text doesn't fit into the height of the AutofitTextView the text overruns.

Comment: @Christian Could you upload your answer layout(.xml) with screenshot of how it looks like in device and how you wanted to  look?

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: @Christian I have updated my answer, could you check now?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to set text size based on how many letters are shown.

You can do this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.your_layout);
if (string.length() > 10) {
    textView.setTextSize(10);
else {
    textView.setTextSize(20);
}
textView.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do it like this

```
textview.setText(“Some text”);
    textview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        if(textview.gettext().toString().length==1)
{
textView.setTextSize(10.0f);
}else{
            int lineCount = textview.getLineCount();
            // Use lineCount here
if(lineCount==1)
{
textView.setTextSize(20.0f);
}else if(lineCount==2)
{
textView.setTextSize(30.0f);
}
}
        }
    });
```

This should give you hold over the text size based on the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.your_layout);
textView.setTextSize(constant-textView.getText().toString().length);
```

Get the TextView text, and set the font-size accordingly to length. e.g - if the `TextView` contains one letter "b" then the size will **constant - 1** , and if it contains two words like "Android Is Cool" then the size will be **constant - 15**, which is smaller.